# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-4

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
    public ActionResult PopulateFromDB(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var context = new NerdDinnerEntities();
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = page,
            sord =sord,
            records = context.Authors.Count(),
            rows = (from n in context.Authors
                    select new
                    { AuthorId = n.AuthorId ,
                        cell = new string[] { n.AuthorId.ToString(), n.Name.ToString(), n.Location.ToString() }
                    }).ToList()
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am writting ToList or Toarray is it not working the error comes :

```
    public ActionResult PopulateFromDB(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var context = new NerdDinnerEntities();
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = page,
            sord =sord,
            records = context.Authors.Count(),
            rows = (from n in context.Authors
                    select new
                    { AuthorId = n.AuthorId ,
                        cell = new string[] { n.AuthorId.ToString(), n.Name.ToString(), n.Location.ToString() }
                    }).ToList()
        };
        return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

Comment: Try with `Convert.ToString` instead of `object.ToString`

Comment: Thanks for reply me but The same error is display Convert.ToString( n.Name) as all the field but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) to convert  this, There is no overload for int so you should cast your number to a double or a decimal.

```
public ActionResult PopulateFromDB(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var context = new NerdDinnerEntities();
    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = 1,
        page = page,
        sord =sord,
        records = context.Authors.Count(),
        rows = (from n in context.Authors
                select new
                { AuthorId = n.AuthorId ,
                  cell = new string[] { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)n.AuthorId), n.Name, n.Location }
                }).ToList()
    };
    return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

You are not using LinqToSql Classes, if you were using that your code should work, but as  you mention that you are using LinqToEntity then You should use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` to convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume your adding a custom property `cell` for display/storage purposes on the client-side. I would avoid this as your essentially coupling your API call to one particular client. I would suggest you simply return the data required & deal with it at the client-side specifically e.g.

**Server**

```
...
select new
{
    Id = n.AuthorId,
    Name = n.Name,
    Location = n.Location
}).ToList();
...
```

**Client**

```
var response = ...
foreach (var author in response)
{
    var cell = new string[] { author.Id.ToString(), author.Name, author.Location };
    // do something with cell
}
```